# HTTP/1.1 401 Access to the HttpFS server is restricted

Tags: hadoop, curl, webhdfs, biginsights

> bivm:/home/biadmin/Desktop # curl -i "http://bivm.ibm.com:14000/webhdfs/v1/tmp/newfile?op=OPEN"
>       HTTP/1.1 401 Access to the HttpFS server is restricted. Please obtain proper credential from the BigInsights Console first.
>       Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
>       Cache-Control: must-revalidate,no-cache,no-store
>       Content-Length: 1589
>       Server: Jetty(6.1.x)

I am getting the above mentioned error, when I am trying to access a file in my cluster using the `WebHDFS REST API` call through the HttpFS server (running on port 14000 by default). Please advice.

Comment: for reading a file, the port number would be different. try to find out the right port number t read  file in webhdfs in "biginsights"